# Non-linear system equilibrium points but critical point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have a question about critical points of nonlinear systems. So I am given the following prey-predator model

$$f(x,y) = x' = 10(1-\frac{x}{k})x-\frac{10xy}{1+x}$$

$$g(x,y) = y' = -y+\frac{10}{4}\frac{xy}{1+x}$$

It follows that x is the prey while y represents the predator population. So solving for this I found that the critical points are given by $(0,0),(\frac{2}{3},\frac{15k-10}{9k}),(k,0)$. I am asked to check for the stability of the equilibrium points for different values of $k$ where:

$0<k<\frac{2}{3}$

$k = \frac{2}{3}$

$\frac{2}{3}<k<\frac{7}{3}$

$k^{*}\approx1.2667$

$k^{*} < k < \frac{7}{3}$

Most of the cases are find except for the point $k=\frac{2}{3}$ where I seem to be getting a jacobian that gives a $0$ eigenvalue. I find such results very odd because I thought that the local behavior at some points cannot results in a $det(A) = 0$. Moreover, I am told that I should find transitions in local behaviour of at least one equilibria at the following values: $K = 2/3$, $K = K^{*} ≃ 1.266$, $K = 7/3$, of which I seemed to get saddle points at critical points $(0,0)$, and $(K,0)$, while the last critical point seems to result in stable nodes except for $k=\frac{2}{3}$.

So I am wondering if someone could clarify whether such results are possible for $k=\frac{2}{3}$. Additionally, I would also like to ask whether saddles are the only transitions and whether others (ie: repeated eigenvalue) also count.

Edit: At $k=\frac{2}{3}$, it follows that the point critical points are (0,0),$(\frac{2}{3},y(\frac{2}{3}) = (\frac{2}{3},0)\text{ since } (\frac{15(\frac{2}{3})-10)}{9\frac{2}{3}} = 0)$ and like wise for the other critical point given by $(k,0) = (\frac{2}{3},0)$. So two of the critical points are the same. Evaluating the jacobian (sorry I didnt realize that I did not write the jacobian down).

$$J(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} f_x = 10(1-\frac{2x}{k}-\frac{y}{(1+x)^2}) & f_y = \frac{-10x}{1+x} \\ g_x=\frac{10y}{4}(\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} & g_y = -1 + \frac{10}{4}(\frac{x}{1+x}) \end{pmatrix}$$

Hence, $$J(\frac{2}{3},0)=\begin{pmatrix} -10 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

As a result, this gives a case where the Trace < $0$ but the Det = $0$ with $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = -10$

Thank you.

Comment: "Most of the cases are find except for the point k=2/3 where I seem to be getting a jacobian that gives a 0 eigenvalue." Please show in detail what you did.

Comment: @Did sorry about that I didnt realize I missed the jacobian. Edited

Comment: Re fixed points where the eigenvalues are $0$ and some $\lambda<0$, would you have problems interpreting the behaviour of the systems $$x'=-x\qquad y'=u(y)$$ near their fixed point $(x,y)=(0,0)$, for $u(y)=y^2$, or $u(y)=-y^2$, or $u(y)=y^3$, or $u(y)=-y^3$?

Comment: Funny that my demand for precisions was met by the acceptance of an answer which, while technically correct, does not touch on the subject of what happens when one eigenvalue is zero. Is this not the heart of your question?

Comment: @Did Sorry I didn't see the 2nd message given that I was looking at it on my phone and couldnt see the math equations. However, I am confused by why this is so because I was originally told that the determinant cannot be 0 for non linear systems. Either I was mislead and this was a misconception or I am just confused.

Comment: ...And all these confusions, misconceptions and the like, still unresolved, are the reason why you *accept* an answer which does not touch them?

Comment: Actually it does make sense after I reasoned it over for a while. I think my way of thinking was too restricted but I noticed that I did do it in the correct method, but that I should have accounted for all possible cases of the system

Comment: Your last comment makes no sense whatsoever to me. But if indeed your confusions, misleads and misconceptions suddenly vanished, I guess everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical points are:
$$(x, y) = \left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{50 (3 k-2)}{9 k}\right),(k, 0),(0, 0)$$

At $k = \dfrac{2}{3}$, these reduce to:

$$(x, y) = \left(\frac{2}{3},0\right),(0, 0)$$

The Jacobian is given by:

$$J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{20 x}{k}-\dfrac{y}{(x+1)^2}+10 &  \dfrac{1}{x+1}-1\\ \dfrac{5 y}{2 (x+1)^2} &  \dfrac{5 x}{2 (x+1)}-1 \end{bmatrix} $$

At $k = \dfrac{2}{3}$, the Jacobian is:

$$J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{y}{(x+1)^2}-30 x+10 &  \dfrac{1}{x+1}-1\\ \dfrac{5 y}{2 (x+1)^2} &  \dfrac{5 x}{2 (x+1)}-1 \end{bmatrix} $$

At the critical point $(0, 0)$, when  $k = \dfrac{2}{3}$, we have the Jacobian:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 10 &  0\\ 0 &  -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

At the critical point $\left(\dfrac{2}{3}, 0\right)$, when  $k = \dfrac{2}{3}$, we have the Jacobian:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -10 &  -\dfrac{2}{5}\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

A phase portrait at $k = \dfrac{2}{3}$ shows:

[image]

It appeared that this and the Jacobian at that point was what was giving trouble, so I stopped there regarding everything else as you claim you did not have issue with those.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the critical point as well. Is $y=\frac{15k-10}{9k}$ not a critical value ?

Comment: At $k = 2/3$, that reduces to zero. When $k \ne 2/3$, you would do an analysis for various choices of $k$. However, I am confused - you said you did all this and even give ranges where you did it.